# How to determine what's causing Chrome to consume cellular data

Tags: chrome-for-android, data-monitoring

**Short:** How can I know why my Android Chrome consumes so much data - which sites, maybe some rogue plugins etc.

**Background:** Recently I've been getting notifications from my carrier and also from my phone that I've exceeded my 12GB/month data plan. Looking in "Mobile data use", I see that that almost all of the data was used by Chrome. I do use Chrome to listen to podcasts (I'm currently considering a dedicated app), but that hasn't changed recently, while data usage have skyrocketed...

**What I tried:**

- I've looked at [`chrome://net-internals`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/docs/crash-course-in-net-internals.md), which my chrome redirects to `chrome://net-export`, but that looks quite heavyweight to be running for days on my phone.
- I've enabled Chrome's DataSaver/Lite Mode (I think it's the same? My phone is not in English, so not sure). It shows usage by site, but the usage shown there doesn't account for the excessive usage reported in mobile data use. The savings were miniscule.
- I'm hoping there's some app/plugin/etc. that I can add to Chrome to summarize data usage. If this exists only for Firefox mobile, I'm willing to switch, though I'd rather not.

**Device:** Samsung Galaxy S7 (SM-G930F), Android 8.0, Samsung Experience 9.0, Chrome 77.0.3865.92.